# Jupyter Notebook no longer recognize Graphlab Create package after update

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I updated my Jupyter Notebook and now it doesn't know anything about some of my installed packages.
For example it generates this error when I ***import graphlab***:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import graphlab
>
> ImportError: No module named graphlab

However, I can import graphlab in python console without any error.

I tried to reinstall graphlab from [this link](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) over and over but nothing changed

I also noticed that ***sys.executable*** gives me different result in python console and jupyter notebook:

> '/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python'

vs

> '/home/user/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/bin/python'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code (run it in Jupyter Notebook).

You probably don't have the correct environment and at the moment cannot change the kernel type.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

It should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks,
It resolved it,
:)
Now i can change the kernels, 
However, I have 4 kernels, is there any way to remove some of them?